# How do I fix this issue mqtt Paho timed out but did not report as connection lost

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I have a problem with my service using paho mqtt. It times out but no report as connection lost. Did anyone have a solution to this problem?

```
public void connect(String client_id) {
        String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        MqttDefaultFilePersistence dataStore = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence( tmpDir );

        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setKeepAliveInterval(120);



        try {
            _client = new MqttClient( _url, MqttClient.generateClientId(), dataStore );
            _client.connect( options );
            _client.setCallback( this );

            _client.subscribe( TOPIC );
            LOGGER.info("Subscribed to " + Arrays.toString(TOPIC));
            LOGGER.info("MAX CORES " + MAX_CORES);

        } catch ( MqttException e ) {
            LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "Mosquitto Error: " + e.fillInStackTrace() );
            connect(null);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void messageArrived(final String topic, final MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
         threadPool.execute(new Runnable(){// code});
    }
```

Using mqtt v 1.0.0

```
Nov 6, 2015 2:36:52 AM org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState checkForActivity
SEVERE: paho-595916529752865: Timed out as no activity, keepAlive=120,000 lastOutboundActivity=1,446,777,172,455 lastInboundActivity=1,446,777,117,734 time=1,446,777,412,455 lastPing=1,446,777,172,454
```

Comment: Your going to have to give us some more context here for anybody to help. Things like, does it time out as part of the connection or after a period of not sending data? What KeepAlive period have you set?

Comment: originally it is 60 seconds , now i changed it to 120 seconds

Comment: any luck on this issue?

Comment: @SherinMathew did you fixed yours using my answer?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix

just set:

`setConnectionTimeout(0)` use zero to disable timeout.

> setConnectionTimeout public void setConnectionTimeout(int
>   connectionTimeout) Sets the connection timeout value. This value,
>   measured in seconds, defines the maximum time interval the client will
>   wait for the network connection to the MQTT server to be established.
>   The default timeout is 30 seconds. A value of 0 disables timeout
>   processing meaning the client will wait until the network connection
>   is made successfully or fails. Parameters: connectionTimeout - the
>   timeout value, measured in seconds. It must be >0;

Hope it'll help out.